# Object's origin in openGL

Tags: opengl

is any way how to preserve object's origin from 3D modeller (blender) different from average geometry (mass) "origin" in openGL? When importing models into openGL via assimp libraly it still gives the origin based on geometry (mass).
Apply position/rotation/scale in blender doesn't help.

For example I need my train model to fit on railroad so I set the origin to the bottom (carriages) but the train is still placed lower. I must correct the z-position of object but when the geometry is not symmetric and the mass-origin point is not placed in the middle it's impossible to get precise result. Thanks for any replay. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "mass-origin." I'll assume you are talking about the origin of the geometry itself, the model-space origin.

Every object in Blender, or any other similar tool, has its own coordinate system. When you place it in a scene, when you move it around or rotating it, you are setting up a transformation from its local model space to the space of its parent object (which may be the world).

Whether that position is stored in your exported file depends entirely on what format you are exporting. But no format is going to actually apply that transformation to the *vertices* of the object; if the transform exists, it will be stored separately.

Collada can store the transforms of each object, and the Open Asset Importer can retrieve them through its scene graph support. But you'll have to figure out what scene node name was assigned to that object, then multiply its transformation matrix up the node hierarchy to get the model-to-world transform.